# Installation of DBD::Sybase with Strawberry Perl

Tags: perl, sybase, dbi

I'm running Strawberry Perl 5.32.0 on an Windows 10 machine and trying to install the DBD::Sybase module. Sybase ASE 16 libraries and headers are installed and working fine with other projects.

I receive the following error messages from cpan:

```
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -llibct.lib
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -llibcs.lib
...
```

Since about Sybase 16 the libraries are named lib**syb**ct.lib, lib**syb**cs.lib, ...

I also receive a lot of linking error messages from cpan like:

```
dbdimp.o:dbdimp.c:(.text+0x10b4): undefined reference to `ct_config'
```

Therefore, the warnings above are most likely not harmless at all.

I had the same problems installing DBD::Sybase on an older Windows 7 machine 2 years ago after upgrading Sybase to version 16, but no problems with earlier Sybase versions.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Re "*the warnings above are most likely not harmless at all.*", They never are :)

Comment: It actually does look for the new file names

Comment: Can you provide the output of `dir /s/b %SYBASE%`

Comment: The output of `dir /s/b/ %SYBASE%` is too long to share it here. I copied it to my Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0sr5dgggh1q1j6b/sybase_dirs.txt?dl=0

Comment: Sorry, asked that to walk through the steps taken by Makefile.PL. I was busy yday, and I am again today

Comment: I checked this myself now. Makefile.PL fails detecting the Sybase version in `getLibVersion` and tries the wrong libraries therefore. I changed the content of `getLibVersion` to `return 16;`, which is the correct version. After `perl Makefile.PL` and `gmake` I get `Makefile:992: *** target file 'Makefile' has both : and :: entries.  Stop.` At line 992 there is `$(FIRST_MAKEFILE) : Makefile.PL $(CONFIGDEP)`. I'm lost again.